# Should an SCN obtained from one RAC node be immediately usable on other RAC nodes?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rac

I'm seeing `ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number` and don't understand why.  The error happens around once a month from a process that runs every few minutes - so very rarely. Running oracle 2 node RAC (11g-r2) linux. Scenario:

on instance 1:

1. get an scn (`my_scn`) via `dbms_flashback.get_system_change_number`
2. use `my_scn` in some queries with no problems: `select ... from X as of scn my_scn`
3. pass `my_scn` to a parallel pipelined function that is used in a query (Note the time from obtaining the scn in step 1 to passing the scn in step 3 is less than a minute and potentially less than a second.)

on instance 2 (oracle chose the instance based on parallel query) in the parallel pipelined function:

1. use `my_scn` parameter in a query like `select ... from Y as of scn my_scn`
2. very rarely get `ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number`

So, my question is: Should an SCN obtained from one RAC node be immediately usable on other RAC nodes?

Comment: SCN is at DB level not instance level, so it should be available immediately. Check with Oracle support if you are encountering any bugs.